Automate Intuit QuickBooks Windows 11 Application
I am trying to automate the Intuit Quickbooks software, preferably using Python. I want to click, scroll, provide keyboard input, extract text etc.
Quickbooks Desktop Screenshot
I tried using gui_automation library gui-automation and it works but it does not have the ability to extract text. All I can do is click and send keyboard inputs. Also it would be better if I could use control based automation library rather than image based.
I tried using pywinauto. First I inspected the UI elements of Quickbooks program (as shown in above screenshot) using UISpy.exe gui-inspect-tool and got as shown in the below image:
UISpy Screenshot
Then I wrote the following code:
from pywinauto import Application
import psutil

# Find the PID of the running Quickbooks process
for proc in psutil.process_iter(["pid", "name"]):
    if proc.info["name"] == "QBW.EXE":
        quckbooks_pid = proc.info["pid"]
        break


# Connect to the existing window by its process ID
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=quckbooks_pid)

quickbooks = app.window(title_re=".*Enterprise.*")

quickbooks.print_control_identifiers()


I get this output:
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - ' Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 24.0 Trial Version'    (L-8, T-8, R1374, B728)
[' Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 24.0 Trial Version', ' Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 24.0 Trial VersionDialog', 'Dialog', 'Dialog0', 'Dialog1']
child_window(title=" Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 24.0 Trial Version", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Pane - 'Workspace'    (L0, T52, R1366, B720)
   | ['WorkspacePane', 'Workspace', 'Pane', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   | child_window(title="Workspace", auto_id="59648", control_type="Pane")
   |    |
   |    | Dialog - 'QuickBooks Trial'    (L2, T54, R1364, B718)
   |    | ['QuickBooks Trial', 'QuickBooks TrialDialog', 'Dialog2']
   |    | child_window(title="QuickBooks Trial", auto_id="65280", control_type="Window")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Edit - ''    (L1, T79, R6, B84)
   |    |    | ['Edit', 'Edit0', 'Edit1']
   |    |    | child_window(auto_id="21573", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | Pane - ''    (L6, T84, R1360, B714)
   |    |    | ['Pane2']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L6, T84, R1360, B714)
   |    |    |    | ['Custom', 'Custom0', 'Custom1']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L6, T84, R1360, B714)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Custom2']
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L656, T372, R710, B427)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image', 'Image0', 'Image1']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="progressGifImage", control_type="Image")
   |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L409, T268, R957, B530)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom3']
   |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="offlineMode", control_type="Custom")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L497, T268, R869, B400)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'Someone accidently unplugged the network.\nWe will be waiting right here until you are up and running!'    (L491, T462, R878, B502)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Someone accidently unplugged the network.\nWe will be waiting right here until you are up and running!Static', 'Someone accidently unplugged the network.\nWe will be waiting right here until you are up and running!', 'Static', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Someone accidently unplugged the network.\nWe will be waiting right here until you are up and running!", auto_id="offlineText", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    | Custom - ''    (L6, T84, R1360, B714)
   |    |    |    |    |    | ['Custom4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L19, T84, R47, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="BackBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L19, T84, R47, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L52, T84, R80, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="ForwardBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L52, T84, R80, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L85, T84, R113, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="RefreshBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L85, T84, R113, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image5']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L85, T84, R113, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="StopBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L85, T84, R113, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image6']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L118, T84, R146, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button5']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HTTPSSecureBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L118, T84, R146, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button6']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HTTPSInSecureBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L118, T84, R146, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button7']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HTTPInSecureBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Edit - ''    (L148, T84, R498, B100)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Edit2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="Address", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar', 'ScrollBar0', 'ScrollBar1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="VerticalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HorizontalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L1286, T84, R1314, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button8']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="CopyBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L1286, T84, R1314, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image7']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L1319, T84, R1347, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button9']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="PrintBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L1319, T84, R1347, B112)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image8']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Progress - ''    (L6, T84, R1360, B88)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Progress']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="BrowserProgressBar", control_type="ProgressBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L6, T88, R1360, B714)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image9']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="PART_image", control_type="Image")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image10']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="PART_popupImage", control_type="Image")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L11, T727, R31, B747)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image11']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="DownloadMessageIcon", control_type="Image")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Edit - 'Another file download is already in progress.'    (L36, T714, R276, B735)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Edit3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Another file download is already in progress.", auto_id="DownloadMessageText", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar3']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="VerticalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HorizontalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Edit - 'You may cancel the current download and try again'    (L36, T737, R276, B759)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Edit4']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="You may cancel the current download and try again", auto_id="DownloadMessageDetailText", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar5']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="VerticalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar6']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HorizontalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - 'OK'    (L286, T725, R351, B749)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button10', 'OKButton', 'OK', 'OK0', 'OK1', 'OKButton0', 'OKButton1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="OK", auto_id="DownloadInProgressMessageOK", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - 'OK'    (L309, T728, R329, B745)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['OKStatic', 'OK2', 'Static2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="OK", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Button - ''    (L1326, T729, R1340, B743)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Button11', 'OKButton2']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HideDownloadProgressBtn", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Image - ''    (L1326, T729, R1340, B743)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Image12', 'OKImage']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | Edit - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['Edit5']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="StatusBarText", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar7']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="VerticalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar8']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HorizontalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")

The control identifiers do not have controls as shown in UISpy. I changed the
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=quckbooks_pid)

part of my code to:
app = Application(backend="win32").connect(process=quckbooks_pid)

But still did not get the controls I needed.
How is the UISpy identifying all the controls properly and pywinauto is not and how can I automate the program?
I am using Windows 11
Any help would be appreciated
